# Bicycle air pump project

Tags: 3d-design, quality

Is a home 3D printer capable of printing a good bicycle air pump?

I've searched the Internet and there is very limited info on it. Things need to be rigid and very minutious in the valve part of the pump. I could give an example of what I thought in the image [image]

Answer (score 2):

## depends

You certainly can print *parts* of **a** bicycle pump, for example, the outer case and maybe the inner piston, maybe even the housing for the connection valves.

However, you cant print the buffer spring or the valves itself. You will have trouble printing the adapters. And you will have to print in ABS to smooth the inside of your pump with acetone vapor, so you have a smooth surface that forms an air seal under operation.

It would be cheaper and more durable to just print just the fittings and use a PVC Pipe as the cylinder itself.

As in all things, if this is a **good** pump depends a lot on design and your machine.

Comment: Good suggestion about using a PVC pipe as the cylinder. Very cheap and easy to come by at just about any hardware store. Plus, walls will be infinitely more smooth than would a printed replacement. Time savings alone (ie: design, print, finishing) would make it well worth it. Comes down to *what is our time worth*.

Comment: Right, I'd use a PVC pipe for keeping an smooth slips.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to print such a product. You should be printing this in a tough material at a fine layer resolution and probably need to machine the inside of the cylinder or use grease and use a rubber valve.

Comment: I'm not convinced -- it's difficult enough to get an airtight cyliinder printed, let alone one that can withstand 100 psi  aka 0.7 MPa

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That is your good right. My colleague printed a 5 bar air pressure air motor, so theoretically it is possible, it depends on the design.

Comment: Cool!  how thick were the walls?